# Count sum ignoring certain cells using offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to count the twelve cells left of my 'total' cell. I am using an offset sum because a new column gets added weekly to the left of 'total' cell. Sum I am using is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(Q8,,-12,1,12))
```

Firstly When I add a new cell the letters change and formula stops working. Second, some of the cells in the twelve have a value of zero, these i need ignoring and counting 12 with values.

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: Why `12`? Are you trying to add from `F8` until the totals cell wherever this latter moves to the right?

Comment: I need to take an average from the past 12 weeks worked and want the sum but if one week the person didnt work it would have a zero so that week needs to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

12 cells from left of Q8 is range - E8:P8

you can use `=SUMIF($E$8:$P$8,">0",E8:P8)`

which would solve both problems ie

- adding new columns after the total columns
- count only cells greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this formula to sum "up-to 12 non-zero cells on the left of the totals cell", supposing the latter is at `Q8`. The formula should move correctly with the cells wjen new cells are inserted on its left.

```
Q8:
=SUMPRODUCT($A8:P8*(13>COUNTIF(OFFSET(Q8,0,COLUMN($A8:P8)-COLUMN(Q8),
   1,COLUMN(Q8)-COLUMN($A8:P8)),">0")))
```

Comment: This works great, only issue is If i were to add in another 10 cells left of the 'totals' cell, It still only reads the values between A8:P8

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShizukaNaHaji Yeah, it's very difficult to dea with this particular case. Is it an option to always leave one blank cell between the cells and the total cell? In this case you can move the total cell to `R8` so it becomes `=SUMPRODUCT($A8:Q8*(13>COUNTIF(OFFSET(R8,0,COLUMN($A8:Q8)-COLUMN(R8),
   1,COLUMN(R8)-COLUMN($A8:Q8)),">0")))`; and now if you insert at `Q8` the formula will move to  `S8` (R8 becomes blank) and it will adjust correctly.